# How to create a pie chart from two variables

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

I'm creating a pie chart in *Jaspersoft Studio*. I have two variables containing integer values. Using those two variables i want to create a pie chart. I tried adding two series and placing the pie chart in summary band but only one series is displaying. So, how am i supposed to create a pie chart from two variables instead of a column in database?

I still don't have the actual database so  i'm using a sample database that comes with jasper studio. I only need two integers and a string so that's why I've used such a query.
[image: 1]

In order to create a pie chart from two variables, I've create two series, put respective expression in both series, placed my pie chart in summary band and executed the code.
[image: 2]

Comment: Provide some screenshot of your design and sample data that you are using

Comment: @viki888 i've updated the ques by adding the images.

Comment: I got what you are trying to do. What is your expected result? If you need some tutorial about pie chart in Jasper report, [refer this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-datasets-jaspersoft-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you are taking `Accepted` and `Rejected` as two separate fields and you need those two data need to be displayed your chart. If this is true, then try modifying your query like below,

```
SELECT count_value, status 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(orderid) as count_value, 'Accepted' as status
       FROM orders
        WHERE shipcountry = 'Germany'
         GROUP BY shipcountry)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT COUNT(customerid) as count_value, 'Rejected' as status
      FROM orders
       WHERE shipcountry = 'Germany'
        GROUP BY shipcountry)
```

Now you will have two fields which is `count_value` and `status`. In pie chart, provide `status` field in **series** and `count_value` in **value**.

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: thnx a lot brother ...my assumption of database was wrong which further led to wrong query and ultimately unachieved results. Appreciate your help.